# bundler: bad interpreter: no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Trying to get bundler to run, greeted with `-bash: /usr/local/bin/bundler: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.  Have tried un installing rbenv reinstalling, uninstalling/reinstalling bundler. Nothing seems to fix this. How do I change the path to for installed bundler?

```
:> gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

This is my current Current Gem ENV:

```
:> gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.0 (2018-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Cherubim/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Cherubim/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/Cherubim/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Cherubim/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/Cherubim/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Cherubim/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/Cherubim/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/Cherubim/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/Cherubim/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin
     - /usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin
     - /Users/Cherubim/.yarn/bin
```

Comment: It kinda sounds like you might have another copy of bundler installed on your computer, try using `which bundler` to see where its going when you try and run bundler.

Comment: Figured it out. The bash profile had a second Path that was overriding the correct path.

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing bundler to the mentioned location.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin/ bundler
```